# Audio Annotations

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on my first assignment of allowing users to annotate the audio files something similar to sound cloud using javascript. But I dont know where to start from. It will great help if someone can point me in right directions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently looking for an audio annotation tool too. Here are two that I've found so far:

- **WaveSurfer.js**:

  - https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js
  - http://wavesurfer-js.org/example/annotation/
- **Peaks.js**:

  - https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js
  - https://waveform.prototyping.bbc.co.uk/
  - http://audiovideo.jeffreyeverhart.com/audio-annotation/peaks.html

Answer (score 0):

This javascript library is what soundcloud use

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

We used it to add html **timed lyrics to a song** -

http://www.wackykites.com

Feel free to grab and use any code you find on our page too if helps, though likely not anotated as just being a fun trial.

Look at the source that relates to the lyrics and times, if these were output from a database of "user comments" they would essentially be "timed comments"